# stopping a qtimer in Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

i have setup a qtimer in main constructor like this.

```
Ball::Ball(QGraphicsItem *parent): QGraphicsRectItem(parent), QObject(){
    // draw rect
    setRect(0,0,50,50);
    QBrush brush;
    brush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
    brush.setColor(Qt::red);
    setBrush(brush);

    // move up right initially
    xVelocity = 0;
    yVelocity = -5;


    QTimer* timer = new QTimer();
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(move()));
    timer->start(15);
}
```

the move() fuction in the timer is executed periodically.

```
void Ball::move(){
    reverseVelocityIfOutOfBounds();
    handlePaddleCollision();
    handleBlockCollision();
    moveBy(xVelocity,yVelocity);
}
```

in the above reverseVelocityIfOutOfBounds(); function, there is a condition like this.

```
// bottom edge - NONE (can fall through bottom)
if (mapToScene(rect().topRight()).y() >= screenH){
```

upon executing this i want to stop the Qtimer. i applied everything i can. but all the time the program close unexpectedly. please any help would be highly appriciated.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you can do is to make the timer a member variable of your Ball class. Then you have a handle to it and can just call timer->stop() in reverseVelocityIfOutOfBounds().

Another thing you could do is to call sender() in move to get a handle to the timer object and pass it to reverseVelocityIfOutOfBounds() (bad style though) and does not work across threads.